# Passing a string from .vbs to Powershell causes 'positional parameter not found error'?

Tags: vba, powershell

I have a tiny .vbs Windows form which accepts a string (computer name). All the script does is use that to assemble and then run a Powershell command for the removal of a file on that particular machine. Here's the script:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim compStr As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim baseStr As String = "-noexit get-childItem " & Chr(34) & "\\" & compStr & "\c$\ProgramData\Sophos\Remote Management System\3\Agent\AdapterStorage\ALC" & Chr(34) & " | where {$_.length -eq 0} | remove-Item"
    MsgBox(baseStr)
    Process.Start("powershell", baseStr)
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

The trouble is, it throws up this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'S
ystem\3\Agent\AdapterStorage\ALC'.
At line:1 char:14
+ get-childItem <<<<  \\P94\c$\ProgramData\Sophos\Remote Management System\3\Ag
ent\AdapterStorage\ALC | where {$_.length -eq 0} | remove-Item
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterB
indingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

However, if I run the Powershell command myself through the blue command shell, it works perfectly. It looks like it's something to do with the spaces in the file path, but I can't get my head round it as the string output by the .vbs looks exactly as it should.

Comment: Try substituting double quotes for singles, change `Chr(34)` to `Chr(39)`

Answer (score 0):

Substitute double quotes for singles - change `Chr(34)` to `Chr(39)`.